# Wordpress page.php query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do page.php in Wordpress like this:

I want to have list of etc. new articles and then I want to show the article but it doesn't work.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<li>Recent articles 
    <ul id="submenu_ul">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $blog_query = 'showposts=5&cat=2&paged='.$paged;
    $posts = query_posts($blog_query);
       while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <li><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
       <?php endif ?>              
     </ul>
</li>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<li>Comments</li>
<li>Ads</li>

</div>

<section id="the_section">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="text"><?php the_content(''); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<h2>Žádne príspěvky</h2>
<p class="text">Litujeme, ale nenašli se žádne príspěvky</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

call [have_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts) after your query, this function checks to see if the current WordPress query has any results to loop over. and also set your data by [setup_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)

```
      <?php $blog_query = 'showposts=5&cat=2&paged='.$paged;
      $post = query_posts($blog_query);
      setup_postdata($post);
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif ?>
```

try this

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to help me. I want to have some sidebar menu and here I want to have list of newest posts.

In this code I want to have only one post, not list of posts...

    <section id="the_section">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="text"><?php the_content(''); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <h2>Žádne príspěvky</h2>
    <p class="text">Litujeme, ale nenašli se žádne príspěvky</p>
    <?php endif ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=4'); ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><span><?php the_time('M d Y') ?></span><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a><?php endwhile;?>
```

just use this code